# Forensic image of hard disk on VMWare using Autopsy

Tags: forensics, vmware

Is there a recommended, forensically sound method of acquiring virtual hard drives on VMWare using Autopsy? Or is it a simple copy and paste?

I’ve used other software like Caine in the past, where you take a copy of a hard disk using a “dd” command. Wondering if there is another method like this using Autopsy.

Comment: I think the best method would me to load a raw format of the disk into autopsy

Comment: just an evidence gathering activity, the idea is evidence must be "untouched", as long as you "proofconcept" evidence is "untouched", does not matter what tool is used right?